# Unable to decrypt TLS 1.3 packets with the keys got using SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback openssl API in Wireshark

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, wireshark, tls1.3

I'm working on a task where i need to decrypt all the TLS 1.3 encrypted packets in wireshark (using Edit->Preferences->Protocol->TLS->pre-Master_secret log filename option) for debugging purpose. so i stored all the keys of TLS 1.3 sessions by setting the call back function with openssl provided API() call back function into a file as shown below:

```
SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback(pCtx_m,Keylog_cb_func);
void Keylog_cb_func(const SSL *ssl, const char *line) {
 // Code to log the line into a file in append mode
}
```

With this, i'm able to decrypt the TLS 1.3 packets with the keys logged into the file for only the below three ciphers in wireshark
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

and the other two ciphers of TLS1.3 TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256 , TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 is not getting decrypted using the keys (in wireshark) opensll API has given though the calls are established over these two ciphers successfully.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251476/openssl-1-1-1-it-supports-only-3-out-of-5-ciphers-tls-1-3/68129832#68129832) in stackoverflow about the default enabled cipher suite but i'm not quite sure about if this issue is something related to that. Could anyone help me to understand what i'm doing wrong here:

## Sample Key File:

SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET dd228de6d3f32ae5d83a9009c2e5908cb71c16d8624f5930dd05cabea3b7cc63 aa48ffe195090f87138caf32a520ecd41644f23f6d778f6436b5e2d697452572

CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET dd228de6d3f32ae5d83a9009c2e5908cb71c16d8624f5930dd05cabea3b7cc63 415e363721b8e204d3e2a2f94682d25792f565770a0f9221e86738d1c540e21b

EXPORTER_SECRET dd228de6d3f32ae5d83a9009c2e5908cb71c16d8624f5930dd05cabea3b7cc63 25276ba5f066f69b6caac00d35e981ff0b7d70e20d541c9435538d32a640ecdc

SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 dd228de6d3f32ae5d83a9009c2e5908cb71c16d8624f5930dd05cabea3b7cc63 9d683bacbb0ce07fa5d0425c2763920f11d98af85c7461a52e26efb6bdaf74b5

CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 dd228de6d3f32ae5d83a9009c2e5908cb71c16d8624f5930dd05cabea3b7cc63 bfca7bc330de3836b0e49619375b504f4d2794206c4ecc7fcd1dfdab363bd36a

SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET cb2136f271de0e168eb92a9f2a6811c76fe87d08c9b4ae374f4efc72ccdc7ea5 1be3cc095c1e336168ab10619c266eaf7a9057edf724d65f3016ba64d642ab0f

EXPORTER_SECRET cb2136f271de0e168eb92a9f2a6811c76fe87d08c9b4ae374f4efc72ccdc7ea5 0cfa53e94a8a6cf085af19a45a062152299b5ccea84cbffe237f136f0854672e

SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 cb2136f271de0e168eb92a9f2a6811c76fe87d08c9b4ae374f4efc72ccdc7ea5 7de206865a34e1b3b004d47075d534ebfd60b47a16ce525f3c0da47c9c78c57f

CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET cb2136f271de0e168eb92a9f2a6811c76fe87d08c9b4ae374f4efc72ccdc7ea5 1a4cad91d84607f44cd6a65cf1e9bcddaf3488d2dcb67b5246995485226dfa5c

CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 cb2136f271de0e168eb92a9f2a6811c76fe87d08c9b4ae374f4efc72ccdc7ea5 be0df5b77fb5edb1785118e6adb119a5820beacb74d01d8cdee344d3feb56488

Wireshark Version: Version 3.6.1 (v3.6.1-0-ga0a473c7c1ba).

Thanks in advance
Prakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's found that wireshark Version 3.6.7 (v3.6.7-0-g4a304d7ec222) itself currently has an issue in the TLS 1.3 packet decryption feature for these two ciphers (LS1.3 TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256 , TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 ) due to invalid-aad-length, and the same would be fixed in the upcoming version. We have reported a bug to the wirshark forum as in the link below

https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/18277